# How to add another Classic Administrator?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I need to let someone access a SQL Database and have no time to study and catch up with all the constantly morphing AD stuff so I want to make her one of the existing subscription Co-Administrators added 9 years ago. I just want to add her (ie her Microsoft account) as a Classic Administrator.

Under IAM, Classic Administrators, I clicked Add, Co-Administrator, and a list of five email-like strings showed up. (I don't know whether these represent e-mail addresses or Microsoft accounts.)

[image]

How do I add another Microsoft account to this list so that I can make her a Co-Administrator?

Comment: why classic though? I dont think any classic PaaS resources exist, questionmark

Comment: I must have misunderstood the meaning of "classic". I thought it meant just the old way of doing things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the Microsoft account (i.e the email address you see in the list in your question) is not existing in the same azure ad tenant of the subscription , you need to invite her (i.e. the Microsoft account) to the tenant first, navigate to the `Azure Active Directory` in the portal -> `Users` -> `New Guest User`, **note** don't forget to accept the invitation email.

Then the Microsoft account will be a guest user in your tenant, just navigate to your subscription and add co-administrator, you can search for the Microsoft account (i.e. the email address).

> I need to let someone access a SQL Database

I am not sure you mean to let her access the SQL database in a management tier or data tier. If you what her to access the data tier e.g. do operations on the data in the tables, you will also need to configure the `Active Directory admin` in the SQL Server, navigate to the SQL Server in the portal -> `Active Directory admin` -> `Set admin` -> invite the user you what -> `Save`, more details see this link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-aad-authentication-configure

Comment: I meant both. Management tier to keep changing the firewall ports as she moves around. Data tier for the application.

Comment: When adding a user in Azure Active Directory, there is a "role", eg Global Administrator.  Then in IAM, when assigning the AD user, there is another "role", eg Owner, Contributor etc. This is all VERY CONFUSING.

Comment: @OldGeezer The first one means azure ad directory role, it is the role of your directory(tenant), see this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/users-groups-roles/directory-assign-admin-roles). The second one means rbac role in your subscription, for more details and difference between the roles, see this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/rbac-and-directory-admin-roles).

Comment: Still unnecessarily overly complex. Once, I configured something in Azure AD by mistake. It started clocking $$$ per minute! I couldn't undo it. Had to call in a Microsoft AD Ranger Ninja from Shanghai. He took over my logged in session and spent 50 minutes before he could turn the freaking thing off. Microsoft had the lead in enterprise security by virtue of Windows AD and the lead in oAuth through Passport/MSN Messenger. They had to bungle things up to reach the current mess.